# The operation couldn't be completed. Mach error - 308 (pic/mig) server died in swift 4 and Xcode 9.2

Tags: swift, xcode

I am getting an error when I run my application on iPhone x and iPhone 6,7,8 plus simulators. But it works fine on iPhone 5,6,7 and 8 simulator. And error that I got is "The operation couldn't be completed. (Mach error -308 -(pic/mig) server died)"

I am using Xcode 9.2, swift 4 and here is the screen shot of my problem :
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case there is a problem in appIcons. I have remove all appIcons from assets then it works fine for me.